# Table-valued type as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create the following stored proc with table-valued type as one of the parameter. However, I'm getting error as

> Incorrect syntax near 'READONLY'.

I've checked many stackoverflow responses which mentions that the reasons could be sql server version. This is what my @@version tells me and looks fine to me

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (RTM-CU14) (KB3158271)

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customer_Select](
@variableTable dbo.CustomVariableType READONLY,
@return BIT = NULL OUTPUT)


AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM Customer

SET @return=1

END
```

Appreciate your help in this regard

Comment: Why do you have the open and closing parenthesis?

Comment: Procedure looks good to me though the table type is not used inside the procedure

Comment: works fine for me. didn't get any errors

Answer (score 0):

It started to work after I restarted SSMS. Weird!!

Comment: Please consider deleting your question or at least accept your own answer so that other people will know that the problem is solved.